# Resharper 7 - Cannot create custom pattern

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.0

When I try to create a new "highlighting pattern" in Resharper, the typing inside the main textbox simply doesn't work. So I'm stuck with the default input (="3") and can't change it at all. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

[image]

My Resharper version: JetBrains ReSharper 7.0.1 Full Edition Build 7.0.1098.2760

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this problem disappeared after I have restarted my computer. Restarting Visual Studio alone didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Unfortunately rebooting didn't help.

Comment: I was having the same problem. Restarting Visual Studio and then opening a solution solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting Visual Studio and **not** opening a solution did the trick. As soon as any solution is open, the main textbox becomes inoperable. This is even true after closing the solution.

Of course you can not save your changes to a solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

I suspended R# (tools=>options=>resharper=>suspend), restarted vs, opened solution, re-enabled R#

JetBrains ReSharper 7.1 C# Edition
Build 7.1.25.234 on 2012-11-13T18:34:00